# Adding ruler in leaflet and toggling grids on map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is there any way to add ruler to map ?
My requirment is to add ruler on map. Something like this along x and y axis.

http://www.cap-ny153.org/A%20UTM%209.gif

I am using leaflet to creat floorplan application and for that I need ruler and grid on map.

Also ,I used SimpleGraticule to draw grid on my floormap. 
I need a toggle button or control to switch on or switch off the grids and rulers on map.

Please suggest if this is possible in leaflet to draw ruler on map and also providing toggle to switch it on and off.

Comment: Are you looking for the built-in Leaflet Scale Control? http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-scale

Comment: No . I am looking for something like this along X and Y axis.  http://www.cap-ny153.org/A%20UTM%209.gif

Answer (score 0):

Since SimpleGraticule just extends from L.LayerGroup(https://github.com/ablakey/Leaflet.SimpleGraticule/blob/master/L.SimpleGraticule.js#L6), you have the option of adding it as a standard overlay layer to Leaflet's layer control...which provides you with a simple checkbox for toggling overlays on and off.Looks something like

```
var sg = L.simpleGraticule(options);
sg.addTo(map);
var overlayMaps = {"Graticule": sg};
L.control.layers(null, overlayMaps).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks @snkashis for your response :) . I resolved it with an alternate solution something like this : <br>  
  function toggleGrid() {
   if (map.hasLayer(graticule)) {
    map.removeLayer(graticule);
   } else {
    map.addLayer(graticule);
   }
  }